# django-ckeditor richtext content can't display normally in the page

Tags: django, django-ckeditor

i ran into a problem,i intergrated the django-ckeditor5 in my django admin and it worked.but as i tried to display the content that i saved from the editored,it went wrong.
for example,i put a centered image in the content,but it displayed differently.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9gPlf.png)
in the editor

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sftqp.jpg)
how it is displayed

i noticed that none of the classes in the html codes generated by the editor is loaded,so i tried to load the styles.css in the django-ckeditor5 static directory,but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

If you have your ckeditor text in template like this:

```
<div class='news_text'>{{item.text|safe}}</div>
```

in css file, you can override like below:

```
.news_text img {
    max-width: 100% !important;
    height:auto;
}
```

Comment: Hello,thanks for the advice,but this is not what i needed,i can't write an article and change the classes in the html codes manually everytime.